# Import package from subdir in another subdir

Tags: java, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
myProject
myProject/src/MyProject.java
myProject/src/mypackage/MyPackage.java // This file has "package mypackage;" at top
myProject/src/implementations/SomeFile.java
```

in SomeFile.java I want to import mypackage and implement an abstract class contained within it. Im my MyProject.java I want to dynamically load all files in the implementations dir using URLClassLoader so that I can execute the functions the classes in implementations implement from the abstract class in MyPackage.java.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide more details: which class should be in which package, which class should be loaded by which classloader, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, using the default package (not defining a package) is not recommended.

You'll want to look into Java's [CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) environment variable. More specifically, you'll want to set Java's CLASSPATH to your project's root. You'll then be able to include 'packages' and classes from other subdirectories.

Comment: The CLASSPATH variable is nearly useless when one uses custom URLClassLoaders to realize some plugin architecture.